# Need help with Joomla's SEF Option - Already tried .htaccess and configuration.php

Tags: joomla, joomla-sef-urls

I need help with SEO Configurations in Joomla. I have been tasked to handle an existing Joomla site for my company. It is a replicate (with different contents) of another joomla directory in the same server.

The funny thing is, on the other Joomla site/directory, the SEO configuration is set to Yes for all 3 options (SEF, rewrite & suffix url), and the site is working perfectly.

For the site that I'm working with, whenever I try to set SEF to ON, I will get a 404 error page. I have tried the instructions on on http://www.scribd.com/doc/2300167/Jooml ... t-SEF-URLs but it is not helping much.

I have configured .htaccess exactly as stated, but the SEF isn't working. One thing I have noticed is that, when I issued the command "RewriteRule (.*) (new user can't post more than 1 link)http://www.google.com/" on the .htaccess , my site was not redirected to Google. Yet again, I am very sure that the apache rewrite is working perfectly, otherwise the SEO configurations on the other Joomla Directory wouldn't be working.

My other attempt was to set the $live_site in the configuration.php to my domain, but it is not working either.

I will really hope a good Samaritan will advise on this issue. The site is suppose to go 'live' today, but I have yet to rectify this problem. !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you have edited the correct .htaccess file.
I had a lot of trouble with Joomla SEF only to discover after a lot of wasted time that I was editing an .htaccess file in the wrong location. Apache installations differe a lot as to how they organise configuation files. The rewrite could well be working for Apache but turned off for the subdirectory corresponding to one of the sites.